# ADEumApplicationWillResignActive what is the meaning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, exc-bad-access

My last relase i really suprised because of very critical CRASH case which occurs when user take an application bacground.

In my crash report tool i seen:

```
 EXC_BAD_ACCESS & KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

-[UIApplication(instrumentation) ADEumApplicationWillResignActive:]
```

What is the reason of this error? Why is it occurs?

**I solved problem by adding below code line in my appdelegate:**

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        NSLog(@"---applicationWillResignActive--"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found meaning of *ADEumApplicationWillResignActive*:

It's about **AppDynamics SDK** our project uses it and because of AppDynamics SDK that crash start to occurs.